# Error de array multidimensional

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist

Buenas tardes compañeros me encuentro con un error que parece muy basico pero desde hace horas estoy y no encuentro respuesta.
lo que quiero hacer en el código es simple

de la lista orden quiero correrla 1 por 1, si el elemento es "subir 2" quiero que lo elimine y agregue 2 "subir 1" en una copia que se llame orden2, esa nueva lista que se crea por cada vuelta quiero que se agregue a mi lista multidimensional "dicNew", entonces esa lista me tendria que quedar algo así:

```
dicNew = [ ["subir 2",  "subir 2", "subir 2"], ["subir 2",  "subir 2", "subir 1", "subir 1"], ["subir 2", "subir 1", "subir 1", "subir 1", "subir 1"], ["subir 1", "subir 1", "subir 1", "subir 1", "subir 1", "subir 1"]]
```

pero en ves de quedarme eso me queda lo que se muestra en el resultado, de abajo, cada vuelta del bucle me general la lista nueva que quiero agregar, pero al final se remplazan todas por la ultima que se genero, la verdad no entiendo, pasa lo mismo en Python, pense que era cosa del lenguaje pero no

```js
            orden = ["subir 2",  "subir 2", "subir 2"]
            orden2 = orden
            dicNew = []
            dicNew.push(orden)
            console.log("arrau inicial")
            console.log(dicNew)

            orden.forEach((element) => {
                if(element == "subir 2"){
                    orden2.shift();
                    orden2.push("subir 1");
                    orden2.push("subir 1");
                    console.log("nuevo orden: ");
                    console.log(orden2);
                    dicNew.push(orden2);
                    console.log("nuevo dicNew: ");
                    console.log(dicNew);
                }
            });

            console.log(dicNew);
```

si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería muchísimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es porque asignas un objeto (el arreglo) directamente a la variable `orden2 = orden` y cuando agregas un nuevo arreglo en `dictNew.push(orden2)`, realmente no estás copiando los valores si no la referencia al espacio de memoria que ocupa dicho objeto, por lo tanto cuando modificas `orden2`, se modifican todas las copias de referencia dentro de tu matriz `dictNew`, para solucionar eso puedes usar el Spread operator o [Sintáxis Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
let orden = ["subir 2",  "subir 2", "subir 2"]
let orden2 = [...orden]
let dicNew = []
dicNew.push(orden)
console.log("array inicial")
console.log(dicNew)

orden.forEach((element) => {
    if(element == "subir 2"){
        orden2.shift();
        orden2.push("subir 1");
        orden2.push("subir 1");
        console.log("nuevo orden: ");
        console.log(orden2);
        dicNew.push([...orden2]);
        console.log("nuevo dicNew: ");
        console.log(dicNew);
    }
});

console.log(dicNew);
```

para saber más sobre como copiar objetos en JavaScript puedes ver los siguientes links:

[Copiar objetos - Platzi](https://platzi.com/blog/como-copiar-objetos-en-javascript-sin-morir-en-el-intento/)

[Copiar objetos - todoJS](https://www.todojs.com/copiar-objetos-en-javascript/)

Comment: De acuerdo con que se esta apuntando a la misma referencia `orden/orden2` pero, si se supone que estoy  siguiendo una secuencia dentro del ciclo `forEach` ¿Porque solo toma `dicNew.push(orden2);` del último ciclo `forEach` y reemplaza con este array, todos los demás elementos de las secuencias previas de `dicNew`? ¿Porque se modifican todas las copias de referencia dentro de la matriz dictNew? ¿Cómo sucede esto?